# template bool function without <>, what does it mean?

Tags: c++, templates

The FLIF image library has the following definition:

```
template bool flif_decode(FileIO& io, Images &images,
    callback_t callback, void *user_data, int, Images &partial_images,
    flif_options &, metadata_options &, FLIF_INFO* info);
```

I have seen template specialization, but that still has angle brackets.
What does this one mean?

Comment: Um, the [original code](https://github.com/FLIF-hub/FLIF/blob/aad2083c2508902f971b7a2aa2564eac2dbc6e3f/src/flif-dec.hpp#L23) says `template <typename IO> bool flif_decode(...)`. Something got lost during copy-paste, possibly the angle brackets were eaten by somebody accidentally parsing as HTML.

Comment: No, in the .cpp file, line 1419.  And the code successfully compiles and runs as written.

Comment: Oh, lie 1419 is s a template instantiation. not definition. The definition is in the header file line 23, and also in the cpp file line 967. Basically, the function supports only two possible values for `IO`, since the definition on line 967 of the cpp is not visible to clients. The only ones that will work are the two that are explicitly instantiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is often able to deduce template arguments in explicit template instantation, which is what this is.

Refer to [temp.explicit] (**exmphasis mine**)

> If the explicit instantiation is for a function or member function, the
>   *unqualified-id* in the *declaration* shall be either a *template-id* or, **where all template arguments can be deduced**,
>   a *template-name* or *operator-function-id*.

The standard provides this accompanying example:

```
template void sort(Array<char>&); // argument is deduced here
```

In your example, the function declaration (which is also a definition) looks like this:

```
template <typename IO>
bool flif_decode(IO& io, /*etc*/) { /*...*/}
```

So when we later see the **explicit** instantiation like this:

```
template bool flif_decode(FileIO& io, /*etc*/);
```

The compiler is able to deduce that `FileIO` is the type you wish to use for `typename IO`